# how to persist main monitor assignment on boot?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

Windows 10, radeon 5700XT GPU

i use three monitors: primary (LG 27UL650, connected via displayport) on desk, secondary (ASUS BE239 - HDMI) next to it, third (Fujitsu B24T-7 - DP->HDMI adaptor) by my bed.

sometimes i turn off monitors one and two and fall asleep watching a movie on monitor 3 with a shutdown timer set. i use the power buttons on the screens so they still have power connected. if primary is turned off at shutdown it does not automatically turn back on with reboot, so windows assigns monitor 2 - which does turn on automatically - as 'main'.

once windows boots system tray is on monitor 2 so i go to display settings where it inevitably says that the LG is 'main' despite not having system tray. so then i set monitor 2 as 'main', confirm, set monitor 1 as main, and confirm again. fwiw the numerical assignment persists just fine - LG is always assigned 'monitor 1', just not 'main'.

what's going on here - is it displayport vs hdmi causing the discrepancy? is there a way to get my LG monitor to turn itself on when windows boots? is there a way to persist the assignment of 'main' to the LG monitor?

thanks!